# problem within one of my mysql class functions?

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote a php class for some mysql proposes like update and inserting data into tables
every thing is going to be ok only 1 function not so well
its the function i wrote to update recorders within tables

```
function update($table=null,$array_of_values=array(),$conditions='FALSE') {
        if ($table===null || empty($array_of_values)) return false;
        $what_to_set = array();
        foreach ($array_of_values as $field => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) && !empty($value[0])) $what_to_set[]="'$field'='{$value[0]}'";
            else $what_to_set []= "'$field'='".mysql_real_escape_string($value,$this->con)."'";
        }
        $what_to_set_string = implode(',',$what_to_set);
        return $this->execute("UPDATE $table SET $what_to_set_string WHERE $conditions");
    }
```

when i tried to use to update some fields it doesn't return any errors and dosen't work at it all

Comment: Need to see your database controller.

Comment: Just a troubleshooting technique, but print out the statement you are actually executing.  Then try executing that exact statement on the mysql command line (basically taking php out of the picture) and see where it is complaining.  Also, php needs to have the proper error reporting level set in your php.ini file to display errors.

Comment: that its what i already did Kevin and this out i find out the problem thank you for the great comment

Answer (score 0):

You've put single quotes around your column names. Identifiers are never enclosed in single quotes except when declaring an alias.

```
UPDATE table SET color = 'red'
```

NOT

```
UPDATE table SET 'color' = 'red'
```

which is what your code produces. If you want to allow reserved words as identifiers, then enclose them in `backticks` not 'single quotes'.

Comment: 1) I can't provide any more help since I don't know whether you made the correct changes

Comment: 2) This function shouldn't exist. Use PDO or mysqli prepared statements. You do not need to roll this on your own, and you're not doing it well. All values don't belong in single quotes, either.